# Batch deletion for Spring data JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, batch-delete

I have around 20k records to be deleted from Spring data JPA query , query is related to deleting all records before some particular date.

I am using below query

```
dao.deleteByCreationDateBefore(new Date());
```

I think this query hits database for each row deletion.

Please let me know is there any way I can use batch deletion here?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spting data doen't support batch  operation.

**try to do it with simple delete if it's possible , like :** it be very fast operation (faster than butch delete)

*delete from SOME_ENTITY/TABLE where CreationDate < new Date()/curentDate*

**if your dao method delete record by record  :** 
But you can do it with hibernate/jpa in dao level , like (example from site with persist) from [Hibernate/JPA Batch Insert and Batch Update Example](http://memorynotfound.com/hibernate-jpa-batch-insert-batch-update-example/):

```
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        Book book = new Book(i, "Hibernate/JPA Batch Insert Example: " + i);
        em.persist(book);

        if (i % batchSize == 0 && i > 0) {
            em.flush();
            em.clear();
        }
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

for hibernate : 
and here is article [How to batch INSERT and UPDATE statements with Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/) , read about 'Configuring hibernate.jdbc.batch_size'. And [Hibernate JDBC and Connection Properties](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-jdbc-properties) options for hibernate for hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size and hibernate.jdbc.batch_size

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i am already using batch for insertion . I wanted to know if there is any batch delete option exist otherwise i use plain hql or sql query.

Comment: if you can , use plain hql or sql query! batch delete is slower than query as you should iterate and delete ,even in batch , and flush it into db. In you have choise batch or query ALWAYS use delete , update  wherever you can

Comment: sbjavateam, i have used HQL to delete all records in one go . It is quite faster. thanks for suggesstion